# VSTO Word 2016: Squiggly underline without affecting undo

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I am working on a real-time language analysis tool that needs to highlight words to draw attention from the writer in Word 2016 using a VSTO add-in, written in .NET4.6.1 with C#. Think of the grammar/spelling check, which adds a squiggly line underneath a word to show you that the word has grammatical or spelling errors. I'm adding a similar feature for some of my own defined rules.

I searched around on adding squiggly lines, and stumbled on `Font.Underline` and `Font.UnderlineColor`. I set this on the range of a word, and it appears to provided that visual stumili I was after to draw attention. There is a problem, though. Every underline I add or underline color I change adds an undo action to the undo stack.

I don't want this to happen, or I want a way to pop the action I just did in code from the stack. The aim is to have the user be able to use CTRL+Z to remove *text* he changed, and not affect my language anlysis result.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled on this question, which is asking exactly the same thing:
[Prevent actions to be added to the word undo redo OR Remove actions from the undo redo CommandBarComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703893/prevent-actions-to-be-added-to-the-word-undo-redo-or-remove-actions-from-the-und)

As @Manu pointed out that same question was also asked over at [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7c516e3-5a11-4553-89e4-04e5c57e3355/prevent-actions-to-be-added-to-the-word-undo-redo-or-remove-actions-from-the-undo-redo?forum=vsto) where the answer was:

> The UndoClear method will empty the list. That's the best you can do.

There is also a similar question on here [Word VSTO override CTRL+Z / CTRL+Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761633/word-vsto-override-ctrlz-ctrly/)
 which suggests the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.UndoRecord` route or MessageHooks in AddIns.

---

After more research I noticed a great idea at the end of this thread: [MSDN Draw my own squigglies on Word document](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4d57b33b-aceb-49d1-8d4c-22f1a9ff7415/draw-my-own-squigglies-on-word-document?forum=vsto) where you keep track of your actions and then skip past them in Undo and Redo operations.

Here is an excellent example of code to do "transactional undo/redo's" [Can I create an undo transaction in Word or Excel? (VSTO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661269/can-i-create-an-undo-transaction-in-word-or-excel-vsto) . You can do this same method in VSTO except for one big problem, as noted by Dirk Vollmar in his answer:

> I don't think that overwriting built-in Word commands is possible using VSTO alone, though

I have overwritten some built-in commands in VSTO using keyboard hooking events to intercept commands: [How to perform .Onkey Event in an Excel Add-In created with Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193055/how-to-perform-onkey-event-in-an-excel-add-in-created-with-visual-studio-2010)
However I'm not sure if you can recreate the Ribbon to intercept button commands. More specifically, the Undo and Redo are built-in galleries in the Ribbon UI and you can do nothing with a built-in Ribbon gallery. And in versions like 2010 the Undo/Redo buttons are in the title bar - and you cannot [add/edit buttons on the title bar using VSTO](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28063982-63db-48cf-8f8e-8067a2c7aa39/in-excel-2010-i-want-to-add-a-button-on-the-title-bar-or-above-the-ribbon-so-that-it-is-always?forum=vsto):

[image]

So if you're concerned with trapping the button commands (*everyone I know uses Ctrl+Z & Y*), you might inject VBA code to get access to `EditUndo` and `EditRedo` events, eg:

```
VB._VBComponent vbModule = VBProj.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(VB.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
String functionText = "Public Sub EditUndo() \n";
functionText += "MsgBox \"Undo Happened\"\n";
functionText += "End Sub";
vbModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(functionText);
```

Main problem with this approach is Trust needs to be granted.

---

Another answer in this same QA
[Can I create an undo transaction in Word or Excel? (VSTO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661269/can-i-create-an-undo-transaction-in-word-or-excel-vsto) is by Mike Regan who answered 3 months after Dirk. He used a hidden document and placed it in the real document when needed to make any amount of VSTO actions a single undo.

Still doesn't solve the problem of preventing an action being recorded in the Undo History.

---

I did try a Registry key to limit the UndoHistory to 0 and reset it back to 100 (in order to disable the History while adding an action), but it appears its only for Excel
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/211922

There maybe an undocumented reg key to disable the Undo/Redo history altogether but it would only be read by Word on startup. I thought the UndoHistory key containing a number would be read before each Undo/Redo, but no luck with this approach at all.

---

It's not an easy problem to solve there are big limitations, so it might be easier to:

a) Accept that your spell/grammer checker Add-In is included in the Undo/Redo list (defeat).

b) Work out where the line/text is on screen and show a transparent tooltip highlighting the problem. This is a lot harder than it seems and is less than ideal, here are two great answers to guide you on this method: [Detecting text changes in Word 2016 from VSTO add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770647/detecting-text-changes-in-word-2016-from-vsto-add-in) or a much simpler approach to detect XY positions from this Microsoft email thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/pKq4PsqD3cM

```
//position dialog relative to word insertion point (caret)
int left = 0;
int top = 0;
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
MSWord.Range r = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection.Range;
MSWord.Window w = Globals.ThisDocument.ActiveWindow;

w.GetPoint(out left, out top, out width, out height, r);

frmPopUp newForm = new frmPopUp();
newForm.SetDesktopLocation( left + width + 2, top - newForm.Height + height );
```

c) Only trap Undo/Redo events by the Keyboard **with Transactional Undo/Redo's** and let users see the atomic Undo/Redo's using the buttons. It would be extremely dodgy to remove the Undo/Redo buttons and that will cause heaps of *Where's my Undo button gone?* support cases. So don't do this, if you're curious, quick access toolobar customization can be done from ".qat" files. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926805

d) Use a Mouse Hook and detect when the Undo/Redo buttons are clicked. Here is the code to hook up the mouse, note this wont play nice with corporate Anti-Virus products and I dont recommend it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2009/02/24/message-hooks-in-add-ins/ or https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook.

e) Try to intercept raw windows messages, eg [Excel CustomTaskPane with WebBrowser control - keyboard/focus issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948205/excel-customtaskpane-with-webbrowser-control-keyboard-focus-issues/31012101) just **beware** as per my comment referencing [BUG: Cant choose dates on a DatePicker that fall outside a floating VSTO Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526118/bug-cant-choose-dates-on-a-datepicker-that-fall-outside-a-floating-vsto-add-in) that message pumps in Office sometimes exhibit weird behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is an easy solution to this problem. From what I've seen, you have two options:

1. You could clear the entire undo stack using [Document.UndoClear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195616.aspx). However, this won't be very user friendly, since all previous actions aren't in the undo list anymore.
2. Work with the [UndoRecord](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821168.aspx) class. Between your calls to `StartCustomRecord` and `EndCustomRecord`, all actions in your code will only generate one item in the undo stack. CTRL+Z will still affect your language analysis, but the whole undo stack won't be as polluted as before.

I know this isn't what you want, [but even Microsoft MVPs don't have a better solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a7c516e3-5a11-4553-89e4-04e5c57e3355/prevent-actions-to-be-added-to-the-word-undo-redo-or-remove-actions-from-the-undo-redo?forum=vsto).

Comment: Thanks! This vastly improves the current situation.